# Remove url from string but leave data in it by php

Tags: php

I have tried for it. But I could not do that, Here is my code

```
 $p = '|<a [^>]*href="http://<some url>[^"]*"[^>]*>.*</a>|iU';

 preg_replace($p, '$1', $a);
```

From above code I get all the link from that text, except the specific url. I want to get all the data in between link tag. Thats all.

Here is the link

`<a href="http://<some url>"> <img src="Some url" alt="DZJarAP" width="213" height="300"></a>`

I want it to be like

`<img src="http://<some url>" alt="DZJarAP" width="213" height="300">`

It may be any tag like img,p,div

Please help me out. Your answer are highly appreciable

Comment: Please provide sample string and desired result

Comment: Why would you use a regex to do that?

Comment: I use < and > to show specific url, I did not write it in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this work using `preg_match` like this

```
preg_match("/^(<.*?>)(.*)(<.*?>)$/", $HTML, $matchs);
$imgsTag = $matchs[2];
```

It return every tag in `<a>`.

Comment: I want all the tags in between link tags. Yes it will, if I use it only for img tag. Well thank you nice try

Answer (score 0):

This should help, if I got the correct question:

```
$p = '|<a href="(.*)">(.*").*(".*)</a>|iU';
preg_replace($p, '$2$1$3', $a);
```

It will result in:

```
 <img src="http://onlinegamesocean.com" alt="DZJarAP" width="213" height="300">
```

That only works if your tag in between has a link starting and ending with quotation marks. The link to replace must be the first quoted parameter.
What a `<p>` and `<div>` tag have to do with a link is not clear from your question.

Comment: sorry i did not get result that I want use that specific url. specific url is google.com

Comment: Can you please post a specific example like Justinas wrote?

Comment: <a title="Call of Duty Advanced Warfare Free Download" href="http://onlinegamesocean.com/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare-free-download/" target="_blank">Download Call of Duty Advanced Warfare</a> I want to get text in between the <a> tag.